# How good is the parallelism of Stream Processing Systems?

Tags: parallel-processing, spark-streaming, apache-storm, flink-streaming

Consider that we are going to compute the average of a number of temperature sensors in a given period of time and this computation will be done in a parallel fashion using a SPE. Usually, this computation is done by at least four UDF:

```
map -> keyBy -> window -> aggregate
```

If my `keyBy` operator is responsible to get the ID of each sensor and I have only 2 sensors, the parallelism of 2 is enough to my application (disclaimer: I don't want to consider how large is the window or the tuples to be fit in memory for now).
If I have 1000 sensors it will be very nice to increase the parallelism. Let's say to 100 nodes.
But what if my parallelism is set to 100 and I am processing tuples only of 2 sensors. Will I have 98 nodes idle? Do Spark, Flink, or Storm knows that they don't have to shuffle data to the 98 nodes?

The motivation for my question is this other question.

- What kind of application and scenario can I implement which shows that the current Stream Processing Engines (Storm, Flink, Spark) don't know how to optimize the parallelism internally in order to shuffle fewer data across the network?
- Can they predict any characteristic of the data volume or variety? or the resources underneath the hood?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *whole point* of `keyBy()` is to distribute items with the same key to the same operator.  If you have 2 keys, your items are literally being split into 2 groups and your max parallelism for this stream is 2.  Items with key `A` will be sent to one operator and items with key `B` will be sent to another operator.

Within Flink, if you want to just distribute the processing of your items amongst all of the parallel operators then you can use [DataStream::shuffle()](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/api/java/).

Comment: yeah. this is already nice. I want an use case which makes the work of a developer harder. Suppose if the scenario varies the quantity of the keys along the time. Sometimes only 2 keys, other times 200 different keys. What are the different ways to implement a Flink application to cope with these scenarios. I suppose there are different ways to get a good performance.